# MAUI GraphicsView mouse click event

Tags: maui

I'm new to *.Net Maui*. Trying to draw my own shapes using `GraphicsView` and `IDrawable`. I would like to have the shapes clickable.

Is there a way how to achieve that? Maybe there is another interface something like `IClickable` I'm not aware of. Or I should use different approach than`GraphicsView`.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this to work using the `TapGestureRecognizer` and a class that implements `ICommand`.

In this example I have the `GraphicsView` as a member called `_view` in the same class that implements both `IDrawable` and `ICommand`, but your design could be different and it should still work.

```
public class Block : IDrawable, ICommand
{
    protected GraphicsView _view = new GraphicsView();

    public Block()
    {
        _view.Drawable = this;

        _view.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
        {
            Command = this
        });
    }

    void ICommand.Execute(object cmdObject) 
    {
        // Handle the Clicked event here
    }

    bool ICommand.CanExecute(object cmdObject)
    {
        return true;
    }

    event EventHandler ICommand.CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { }
        remove { }
    }

    public void Draw(ICanvas canvas, RectF dirtyRect)
    {
        // Draw on canvas here
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this merely detecting a click anywhere on the GraphicsView? If you draw shapes on that GraphicsView, it won't tell you which shape was clicked.

Comment: I treid this, and indeed Clicks are recognized, but cmdObject is always null. No way to find out where the click has been.

Answer (score 1):

GraphicsView has a 'StartInteraction' event that can be used to get click/touch information.

See more here: [IGraphicsView.StartInteraction(PointF[])](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.graphicsview.startinteraction?view=net-maui-7.0)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `StartInteraction`/`EndInteraction`. These are two event handlers of `GraphicsView`. `StartInteraction` gets the `ButtonDown` event and `EndInteraction` gets the `ButtonUp` event.

```
view.StartInteraction += OnStartInteraction;
view.EndInteraction += OnEndInteraction;


void OnStartInteraction(object Sender, TouchEventArgs evt) {
        PointF p = evt.Touches.FirstOrDefault();
        Trace.WriteLine($"Touch/click at {p}");
}

void OnEndInteraction(object Sender, TouchEventArgs evt) {
        PointF p = evt.Touches.LastOrDefault();
        Trace.WriteLine($"Released at {p}");
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the TouchEventArgs doesn't have information about which button was pressed (on platforms that support that)

Answer (score 0):

Via XAML you would add a TapGestureRecognizer like this:

```xaml
<GraphicsView
    x:Name="xyz"
    Drawable="{StaticResource drawable}"
    .../>
    <GraphicsView.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnGraphicsViewTapped"/>
    </GraphicsView.GestureRecognizers>
</GraphicsView>
```

The EventHandler looks like this:

```cs
private void OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped(object sender, TappedEventArgs args)
{
}
```

Alternatively, the PointerGestureRecognizer is also available.
( Swipe, Pinch, Pan, Pointer Drag and Drop GestureRecognizer are also available and used similarly. )